# Wordpress categories redirecting to index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello and good day to all!

I started developing a wordpress theme from scratch, and everything seemed to be going well so far. But now I have a small problem. When I click on one of the Post categories in my default wp sidebar, I get redirected to index.php, despite the fact that the link is referencing the exact name of the category.

How can I fix that, so when I click a category, I get the posts that are in that category?

My guess is that this must be a problem with my archive.php page or something like that. I am new to all of this, so please excuse my question.

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an **archive.php** template? What is your front page set to?

Comment: Yes. My archive.php page uses the default template from the wordpress codex. I have created a page for it and applied the template to it. But that doesn't seem to do the job. I get some scattered jibberish like pointless searchbars and monthly categories, but that is all that is in that default archive.php template from the codex. How can I modify it correctly?

Comment: use category.php for your category listing

Comment: Yes, I just added a category.php following this guide > http://bit.ly/1uMC6UC

There I found the order in which wordpress seeks the category output:

category-slug.php → category-id.php → category.php → archive.php → index.php

But I get an error with the code they have provided it gives me a blank page that says:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in ..... Just below the start of the Loop, but everything seems fine on this line of code.

Comment: The markup in that example is wrong. You need to add a `?>` closing PHP tag after `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`. I'm sure you know this...

Comment: I just added the code below. Thank You guys! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix my problem thanks to anstrangel0ver's refference to the category.php file, which led me to http://bit.ly/1uMC6UC , but the code there has a little mistake that I just fixed, so here it is:

I must place this in category.php file in order for me to fix my issue:

```
<?php
/**
* A Simple Category Template
*/

get_header(); ?>

<section id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php // Check if there are any posts to display ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>

            <div class="entry">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <p class="postmetadata"><?php comments_popup_link( 'No comments yet', '1 comment', '% comments', 'comments-link', 'Comments closed'); ?></p>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

NOTE: This is just a generic file structure, so it has to me modified according to Your needs.